# Unsupervised 1D clustering with sparse data

Tags: clustering, overfitting, unsupervised-learning, model-evaluation, sparse

I am developing an **unsupervised 1-dimensional clustering algorithm** to detect regions of a protein in which genetic variants found in a population tend to concentrate.
The analyzed data structure is a NxM binary matrix, where N is the number of individuals in the population and M is the number of amino-acids forming the protein sequence. Analyzed variants are rare, so **the mutation matrix is very sparse**.
The algorithm is based on a sliding window scanning the sequence, and uses the binomial test to check if there is a significant over-representation of variants within the window.

The most critical aspect is which window size to use. The algorithm starts by trying different pre-defined window sizes between 5% and 95%, and iteratively picks the best one and scans around it to find the optimal window, until a performance plateau is reached.

The way in which I measure the algorithm performance is checking the **absolute difference between sensitivity and specificity**, considering a smaller difference an indicator of a better, more balanced performance. This because with very small window sizes, I end up with overfitting: all single amino-acids with recurrent variants are identified as separate clusters. In this situation sensitivity is low (only amino-acids with recurrent variants are considered clusters) but specificity is high (no variant-free amino-acid is within a cluster). On the contrary, very large window sizes often cause the opposite issue, with the algorithm detecting a single cluster starting at the first variant and ending at the last (sensitivity = 1, specificity very low).

All performance measures that I tried rank results obtained with very small window sizes (the overfitting case) as being better. This is due to data being very sparse, and to the consequent imbalance between FP, FN, TP and TN.

So far, I am satisfied with the results obtained with this approach, but I don't know whether the strategy is appropriate, and I would really value the opinion of someone more expert than me in statistics.

In a case like this, **is minimizing the difference between sensitivity and specificity an appropriate strategy to avoid both overfitting and missing important information?**

Any opinion would be greatly appreciated, thank you!